# change Firebase Rules in realtime db

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i try to save my data in realtime database from "hackers". I know that in this database we can set some rules. I have this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
  }
```

Well, my database can read and write data always, but this rules unsecure. Can I use my variables which in my application, for example:

```java
int a;
```

can i use in firebase like this?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": if (a==0),
    ".write": if(a==0)
    }
  }
```

?=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [validate the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) that can be written to your database with a `.validate` rule. For example, to ensure that `a` is a number:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "a": {
      ".validate": "a.isNumber()"
    }
  }
}
```

This ensure that any value written to `a` from a client-side SDK is a number. If you also want to prevent deleting of `a`, you need to add a `.write` rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "a": {
      ".validate": "a.isNumber()",
      ".write": "newData.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend reading the documentation on security rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) (watch the video too) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started), as it has good practical examples.